# Compile C embedded with Julia using intel compiler

Tags: c, compilation, julia, icc

In this [julia doc page](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/embedding/), it introduces method embedding Julia into C

The first example is

```
#include <julia.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* required: setup the julia context */
    jl_init(NULL);

    /* run julia commands */
    jl_eval_string("print(sqrt(2.0))");

    /* strongly recommended: notify julia that the
         program is about to terminate. this allows
         julia time to cleanup pending write requests
         and run all finalizers
    */
    jl_atexit_hook(0);
    return 0;
}
```

the doc says, it can be compiled using

```
gcc -o test -fPIC -I$JULIA_DIR/include/julia -L$JULIA_DIR/lib/julia test.c -ljulia $JULIA_DIR/lib/julia/libstdc++.so.6
```

What I want to know is if I don't have gcc(I am using win8 system), but I have intel parallel studio installed. Then how to compile the above code with intel icl?

The only thing I know is

icl /I $JULIA_DIR/include/julia

but what about libs? How can I add them? I search "intel c++ compiler reference", just can't get an answer, so frustrated.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/581612 Is this the reference you were looking for?

Comment: Hi, @AlexanderMorley. I saw this page. But I can not understand it, when come to practice, like I said, I only know how to include header dir

Comment: I think you have to use an options file or something like that but I haven't got a windows environment to hand so can't be more helpful sorry!